# CakePHP: Automatically filter multi-selection input field based on value selected from drop-down

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

If I have a drop-down list with the following values:

```
A1
B1
C1
D1
```

And I also have a multi-selection drop-down with values like this:

```
A1 : Some value
A1 : Some other value
B1 : Some value
B1 : Some other value
C1 : Some value
C1 : Some other value, etc.
```

How can I filter list #2 based on the value chosen from list #1, so that my users only see A1 values in list #2 if A1 is selected? The values in list #2 are from a virtual field defined in my model, and these fields are part of a simple search engine. I need to do this using a postback, so that the user is returned to this same page after selecting from list #1. The user would then make his selections from the filtered list #2 and click Submit to run the search.

I've little experience with using JavaScript in a CakePHP environment. I assume I need something like 'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()'.

Field #1

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('mission_id', array(
'label' => 'Mission ID', 
'empty' => 'Select')
); ?>
```

Field #2:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('or_identity', array('label' => 'Identity', 
                'multiple' => true, 
                'div'=>false, 
                'class' => 'chosen', 
                'options' => $identities)); ?>
```